# ActiveAdmin menu ordering for Admin Comments model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

How can I change the order for the ActiveAdmin Comments model?
With my own models I use

```
  menu priority: NUMBER
```

in the Admin class. But what about its own Comments class?

Comment: Have you solved this in some way?

Comment: Yes, I found a workaround using negative numbers for menus preceding Comments option.

Comment: You should post this as an answer to the question since there don't seem to be any other options.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a similar problem with ActiveAdmin 1.0beta and wanted to post my solution for posterity.

In initializers/active_admin.rb if you add the "Comments" as a label and disable them in the menu you can move the comments to a dropdown or to the end of the main menu list.

```
config.show_comments_in_menu = false
# if active_admin >= 1.0, use `config.comments_menu = false`
#....
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.build_menu do |menu|
    menu.add label: 'Dashboard', priority: 0
    menu.add label: 'Revenue', priority: 3
    menu.add label: 'Costs', priority: 4
    menu.add label: 'Categories', priority: 5
    menu.add label: 'Users & Comments', priority: 6
    menu.add label: 'Comments', parent: 'Users & Comments', url: "/admin/comments"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays, you can set the Comments menu priority in `config/active_admin.rb` like so:

```
config.comments_menu = { priority: 1 }
```

Comment: One can also set a parent with this menu. This is the way to go since active_admin 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I've found was using negative numbers for menus that I want to be sure are shown before the Comments model.

Answer (score 0):

Answer similar to accepted response, however, for those that want to maintain other AA menu defaults.

```
config.show_comments_in_menu = false

config.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.build_menu :default do |menu|
    menu.add label: 'Comments', parent: 'Misc', url: "/admin/comments"
  end
end
```